# ANT Landscape erode option?

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on

I have just updated to Blender 2.79 and was playing around with the updated ANT landscape add-on when I noticed a new option called Landscape Eroder, this has the potential to be really cool but I can't seem to get it to erode the landscape mesh. All it does is sit for a while processing and before spiting out vertex groups.

What do I with these? They are vertex groups so I can't use them in materials and their doesn't seem to be another part of the add-on that can use them.

Edit: Here is some extra information. All I did was add a landscape with the ANT add-on, the only thing I changed from the default vales is the x and y subdivisions, which I changed to 256 by 256. Then I ran the landscape eroder tool from the landscape tools section of tools panel, leaving it on the default values. It then proceeds to hang for a few seconds, apparently processing, as blender's CPU usage jumps. Afterward the only change is the addition of 10 new vertex groups and the model being triangulated. I am using Blender 2.79 on a mid 2015 Retina Display iMac running OS X 10.11.6.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. What settings are you using?

Comment: While not an answer, there is a tutorial that addresses the use of erosion and using another addon to convert weight paintss to vertex colors. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3k0rXQTyvg The "Weights to Vertex Colors" addon is mentioned at about the 10:30 mark of the video.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to create world with erosion try world machine : [Download it here](https://www.world-machine.com/download.php). The demo version allows you to export the landscape in low resolution. (You can cheat it by exporting smaller tiles (instead of a big one))